# Implementing semantic versioning with git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

everyone. I’m working on a project with following structure:

```
src/
  ExternalLib1/
  ExternalLib2/
  ExternalLib3/
  Main/
  other files…
```

Where `ExternalLibX` are git submodules and supported by other developers in my team, `Main` and `other files` - is my project.

My `.gitmodules` file sets all submodule branches to `develop` branch.

I want to implement git semantic versioning and I can’t figure out how it can be done.

For example: my colleague updates ExternalLibX module from version v1.0.0 to v1.1.0.
After that he send a notification about that and I need to update Main project.
Now I’m doing it with

```
cd ExternalLibX
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
```

But after that I also need to update the version into Main project, how can I do that?

I can solve it by changing submodule branches from `develop` to specific commits, and make a version update in `Main` after any commit sha change in `.gitmodules`, but it seems not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can solve it by changing submodule branches from develop to specific commits

That is what a submodule is: a specific commit (plus an URL to a remote repository).

If your colleague creates a `tag v1.1.0` on `ExternalLib1` (just this one), you need to go to `ExternalLib1/` folder, checkout `v1.1.0`, `cd` back to `src/`, add and commit the new state.